# Formatting Javascript sub strings using Jade

Tags: javascript, string, pug

I have a javascript string that I need to split by format type written inside the string so that I can output bold and italic text in jade such that

```
"Hello {b World b}{i and everyone i} else! And {i hello to you i}. 1 < 5."
```

would output:

Hello **World** *and everyone* else! And *hello to you*. 1 < 5

The string contains an indeterminate amount of these tags (0+) in any order, but I only care about "i" and "b" tags.  I've tried a simple string.replace and tried injecting html:

```
- line = line.replace("{b ", "<b>");
- line = line.replace(" b}", "</b>");
- line = line.replace("{i ", "<i>");
- line = line.replace(" i}", "</i>");
| #{line}
```

But the jade template tries to be smart and outputs:

```
"Hello <b>World</b><i>and everyone</i> else! And <i>hello to you</i>. 1 < 5"
```

because it converts each to

```
&lt; and &gt;
```

Note that the string may contain < or > inside. I'm totally stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [GitHub README](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#readme)

We can also utilize the unescaped variant !{html}, so the following will result in a literal script tag:

```
- var html = "<script></script>"
| !{html}
```

Comment: This is perfect. I can't believe that so many searches didn't bring that up.  Thanks!

Comment: If this solves your problem, please mark the question as answered